# What is the correct way to use Intel Advisor on a remote machine?

Tags: parallel-processing, intel, remote-server, intel-parallel-studio, intel-advisor

Intel VTune Amplifier has the possibility to profile a parallel application executed [on a remote machine](https://software.intel.com/en-us/linux_target_setup).

Intel Advisor doesn't have such an option. According to [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-advisor-cli-mpi) document, you have to use the command-line version of Intel Advisor:

> This makes it possible to automate many tasks as well as analyze an
>   application running on **remote hosts**

However, the GUI version has many features not offered by the cl version (like suggestions about how to solve vectorization/multi-thread inefficiency etc).

I tried to run `advixe-cl` on the remote machine and then copy locally the project (and produced results). It works, but some features are lost. As last chance I tried to `ssh -X` the remote machine and the use `advixe-gui`, but it seems that the main core of my Xeon Phi KNL is too weak to ruun properly such a graphic application.

What is the correct/best use of Intel Advisor in such a scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is described by you here: *"run advixe-cl on the remote machine and then copy locally the project"*. 
But you mentioned that "some features were lost". What did you loose exactly?

The key defficiency of given command-line+GUI approach is that you may not see your source code in "Source View" tabs initially. To overcome this limitation, you have to adjust Project Properties of your local project copy and specify "Source Search" and sometimes to "Binaries/Symbol Search" specifying directories providing path to the location where original source code and sometimes executable binarry plus DWARF/pdb debug info files are located.

[image: Specifying Search Dirs when opening local copy of result]

In case you used "-no-auto-finalize" option in command line (which is more advanced scenario), you may also need to use Re-Finalize feature (available only starting from 2017 Update 2 new release) or (for older versions) make sure that you provide Binary/Symbol/Source Search after opening local project copy, but *before* "Show My Result" upload data action.

Comment: could you please give a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480830/where-should-i-put-annotate-iteration-task) question?

Comment: Also consider upvote and overall recognize answers if they help you.