# Where should I put ANNOTATE_ITERATION_TASK?

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, code-analysis, intel-parallel-studio, intel-advisor

I'm using Intel Advisor to analyze my parallel application. I have this code, which is the main loop of my program and where is spent most of the time:

```
   for(size_t i=0; i<wrapperIndexes.size(); i++){
       const int r = wrapperIndexes[i].r;
       const int c = wrapperIndexes[i].c;
       const float val = localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].cur.at<float>(wrapperIndexes[i].r,wrapperIndexes[i].c);
       if ( (val > positiveThreshold && (isMax(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].cur, r, c) && isMax(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].low, r, c) && isMax(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].high, r, c))) ||
            (val < negativeThreshold && (isMin(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].cur, r, c) && isMin(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].low, r, c) && isMin(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].high, r, c))) )
          // either positive -> local max. or negative -> local min.
            ANNOTATE_ITERATION_TASK(localizeKeypoint);
            localizeKeypoint(r, c, localCurSigma[wrapperIndexes[i].i], localPixelDistances[wrapperIndexes[i].i], localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i]);
   }
```

As you can see, `localizeKeypoint` is where most of the time the loop is spent (if you don't consider the `if` clause). I want to do a Suitability Report to estimate the gain from parallelizing the loop above. So I've written this:

```
   ANNOTATE_SITE_BEGIN(solve);
   for(size_t i=0; i<wrapperIndexes.size(); i++){
       const int r = wrapperIndexes[i].r;
       const int c = wrapperIndexes[i].c;
       const float val = localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].cur.at<float>(wrapperIndexes[i].r,wrapperIndexes[i].c);
       if ( (val > positiveThreshold && (isMax(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].cur, r, c) && isMax(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].low, r, c) && isMax(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].high, r, c))) ||
            (val < negativeThreshold && (isMin(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].cur, r, c) && isMin(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].low, r, c) && isMin(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].high, r, c))) )
          // either positive -> local max. or negative -> local min.
            ANNOTATE_ITERATION_TASK(localizeKeypoint);
            localizeKeypoint(r, c, localCurSigma[wrapperIndexes[i].i], localPixelDistances[wrapperIndexes[i].i], localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i]);
   }
   ANNOTATE_SITE_END();
```

And the Suitability Report given an excellent 6.69x gain, as you can see here:

[image]

However, launching dependencies check, I got this problem message:

[image]

In particular see "Missing start task".

In addition, if I place `ANNOTATE_ITERATION_TASK` at the beggining of the loop, like this:

```
   ANNOTATE_SITE_BEGIN(solve);
   for(size_t i=0; i<wrapperIndexes.size(); i++){
        ANNOTATE_ITERATION_TASK(localizeKeypoint);
       const int r = wrapperIndexes[i].r;
       const int c = wrapperIndexes[i].c;
       const float val = localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].cur.at<float>(wrapperIndexes[i].r,wrapperIndexes[i].c);
       if ( (val > positiveThreshold && (isMax(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].cur, r, c) && isMax(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].low, r, c) && isMax(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].high, r, c))) ||
            (val < negativeThreshold && (isMin(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].cur, r, c) && isMin(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].low, r, c) && isMin(val, localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i].high, r, c))) )
          // either positive -> local max. or negative -> local min.
            localizeKeypoint(r, c, localCurSigma[wrapperIndexes[i].i], localPixelDistances[wrapperIndexes[i].i], localWrappers[wrapperIndexes[i].i]);
   }
   ANNOTATE_SITE_END();
```

The gain is horrible:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

```
INTEL_OPT=-O3 -simd -xCORE-AVX2 -parallel -qopenmp -fargument-noalias -ansi-alias -no-prec-div -fp-model fast=2
INTEL_PROFILE=-g -qopt-report=5 -Bdynamic -shared-intel -debug inline-debug-info -qopenmp-link dynamic -parallel-source-info=2 -ldl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use second approach, where you put ANNOTATE_ITERATION_TASK at the very beginning of loop annotation. Otherwise you get (a) wrong performance projection in Suitability, (b) Missing Start task in Correctness.

If you run Correctness for the second variant (where you put iteration task at the very beginning of loop body), then Correctness should be OK.

Your second Suitability chart is not horrible. It just says that you have to take care about task chunking (click on the "chunking" link in the tool to learn more about it). Fortunately, in fresh OpenMP chunking is "good enough" by default, see https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-loop-scheduling . So in order to see the Advisor projection with chunking ON, you just need to switch ON corresponding check-box and it will not be that bad.

Comment: So...."Task Chunking" is it just `#pragma omp parallel for` (in case of OpenMP, of course)?

Comment: another question: why there is "no information available" in so many columns of the second image? I added the compiler flags to the question

Comment: I did as you said but I keep seeing "Missing start task"

Comment: You are right about Task Chunking. For Correctness (missing start task) it looks like an obvious bug, possibly caused by the fact that compiler has done specific optimization. You may submit the bug via intell support (if you have it), or otherwise you can post a question with attached application on IDZ forum. You can also post it here if you strongly prefer, but I'm just stackoverflow member, not intel support person, so it's hard to promise I can directly help.

Comment: Regarding "No Information Available": these other columns are populated once you run Memory Access Pattern analysis step. You can do that with your most recent annotated version just fine

Comment: I've already done a post there on IDZ, no answer yet. I'll try to send a bug report

Comment: And "Memory Access Pattern" analysis type is available if you switch to "Vectorization workflow" (it's a last "2.2" step in Workflow pane)

Comment: IDZ is enough I guess. It would be better if you attach your application (binary/exe compiled with annotations) to your forum post

Comment: could you please give a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844396/how-should-i-interpreter-these-vtune-results) question?