# How should I interpreter these VTune results?

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing, intel-vtune, intel-ipp

I'm trying to parallelyzing [this](https://github.com/perdoch/hesaff) code using OpenMP. OpenCV (built using  IPP for best efficiency) is used as external library.

I'm having problems unbalanced CPU usage in `parallel for`s, but it seems that there is no load imbalance. As you will see, this could be because of `KMP_BLOCKTIME=0`, but this could be necessary because of external libraries (IPP, TBB, OpenMP, OpenCV). In the rest of the questions you will find more details and data that you can download.

These are the Google Drive links to my VTune results:

[c755823 basic KMP_BLOCKTIME=0 30 runs](http://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_k9tb8CWgn-SEZPQ0JmNEZOR1k) : basic hotspot with environment variable KMP_BLOCKTIME set to 0 on 30 runs of the same input

[c755823 basic 30 runs](http://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_k9tb8CWgn-aFZRWjZSU1pwcDg) : same as above, but with default KMP_BLOCKTIME=200

[c755823 advanced KMP_BLOCKTIME=0 30 runs](http://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_k9tb8CWgn-QllFR1JBOVpiM2c) : same as first, but advanced hotspot

For those who are interested, I can send you the original code somehow.

On my Intel i7-4700MQ the actual wall-clock time of the application on average on 10 runs is around 0.73 seconds. I compile the code with `icpc` 2017 update 3 with the following compiler flags:

```
INTEL_OPT=-O3 -ipo -simd -xCORE-AVX2 -parallel -qopenmp -fargument-noalias -ansi-alias -no-prec-div -fp-model fast=2 -fma -align -finline-functions    
INTEL_PROFILE=-g -qopt-report=5 -Bdynamic -shared-intel -debug inline-debug-info -qopenmp-link dynamic -parallel-source-info=2 -ldl
```

In addition I set `KMP_BLOCKTIME=0` because the default value (200) was generating an huge overhead.

We can divide the code in 3 parallel regions (wrapped in only one `#pragma parallel` for efficiency) and a previous serial one, which is around 25% of the algorithm (and it can't be parallelized).

I'll try to describe them (or you can skip to the code structure directly):

1. We create a `parallel` region in order to avoid the overhead to create a new parallel region. The final result is to populate the rows of a matrix obejct, `cv::Mat descriptor`. We have 3 shared `std::vector` objects: (a) `blurs` which is a chain of blurs (not parallelizable) using `GuassianBlur` by OpenCV (which uses the IPP implementation of guassian blurs)  (b) `hessResps` (size known, say 32) (c) `findAffineShapeArgs` (unkown size, but in order of thousands of elements, say 2.3k) (d) `cv::Mat descriptors` (unkown size, final result). In the serial part, we populate `blurs, which is a read only vector.
2. In the first parallel region,`hessResps` is populated using `blurs` without any synchronization mechanism.
3. In the second parallel region `findLevelKeypoints` is populated using  `hessResps` as read only. Since `findAffineShapeArgs` size is unkown, we need a local vector `localfindAffineShapeArgs` which will be appended to `findAffineShapeArgs` in the next step
4. Since `findAffineShapeArgs` is shared and its size is unkown, we need a `critical` section where each `localfindAffineShapeArgs` is appended to it.
5. In the third parallel region, each `findAffineShapeArgs` is used to generate the rows of the final `cv::Mat descriptor`. Again, since `descriptors` is shared, we need a local version `cv::Mat localDescriptors`.
6. A final `critical` section `push_back` each `localDescriptors` to `descriptors`. Notice that this is extremely fast since `cv::Mat` is "kinda" of a smart pointer, so we `push_back` pointers.

This is the code structure:

```
cv::Mat descriptors;
std::vector<Mat> blurs(blursSize);
std::vector<Mat> hessResps(32);
std::vector<FindAffineShapeArgs> findAffineShapeArgs;//we don't know its tsize in advance

#pragma omp parallel
{
//compute all the hessianResponses
#pragma omp for collapse(2) schedule(dynamic)
for(int i=0; i<levels; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= scaleCycles; j++)
    {
       hessResps[/**/] = hessianResponse(/*...*/);
    }

std::vector<FindAffineShapeArgs> localfindAffineShapeArgs;
#pragma omp for collapse(2) schedule(dynamic) nowait
for(int i=0; i<levels; i++)
    for (int j = 2; j < scaleCycles; j++){
    findLevelKeypoints(localfindAffineShapeArgs, hessResps[/*...*], /*...*/); //populate localfindAffineShapeArgs with push_back
}

#pragma omp critical{
    findAffineShapeArgs.insert(findAffineShapeArgs.end(), localfindAffineShapeArgs.begin(), localfindAffineShapeArgs.end());
}

#pragma omp barrier
#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic) nowait
for(int i=0; i<findAffineShapeArgs.size(); i++){
{
  findAffineShape(findAffineShapeArgs[i]);
}

#pragma omp critical{
  for(size_t i=0; i<localRes.size(); i++)
    descriptors.push_back(localRes[i].descriptor);
}
}
```

At the end of the question, you can find `FindAffineShapeArgs`.

I'm using Intel Amplifier to see hotspots and evaluate my application.

The OpenMP Potential Gain analsysis says that the Potential Gain if there would be perfect load balancing would be 5.8%, so we can say that the workload is balanced between different CPUs.

This i the CPU usage histogram for the OpenMP region (remember that this is the result of 10 consecutive runs):

[image]

So as you can see, the Average CPU Usage is 7 cores, which is good.

This OpenMP Region Duration Histogram shows that in these 10 runs the parallel region is executed always with the same time (with a spread around 4 milliseconds):

[image]

This is the Caller/Calee tab:

[image]

For you knowledge:

- `interpolate` is called in the last parallel region
- `l9_ownFilter*` functions are all called in the last parallel region
- `samplePatch` is called in the last parallel region.
- `hessianResponse` is called in the second parallel region

Now, my **first question is:** how should I interpret the data above? As you can see, in many of the functions half of the time the "Effective Time by Utilization` is "ok", which would probably become "Poor" with more cores (for example on a KNL machine, where I'll test the application next).

Finally, this is the Wait and Lock analysis result:

[image]

Now, this is the first weird thing: line `276` Join Barrier (which corresponds to the most expensive wait object`) is`#pragma omp parallel`, so the beginning of the parallel region. So it seems that someone spawned threads before.  Am I wrong?  In addition, the wait time is longer than the program itself (0.827s vs 1.253s of the Join Barrier that I'm talking about)! But maybe that refers to the waiting of all threads (and not wall-clock time, which is clearly impossible since it's longer than the program itself).

Then, the Explicit Barrier at line 312 is `#pragma omp barrier` of the code above, and its duration is 0.183s.

Looking at the Caller/Callee tab:

[image]

As you can see, most of wait time is poor, so it refers to one thread. But I'm sure that I'm understanding this. **My second question is:** can we interpret this as "all the threads are waiting just for one thread who is staying behind?".

`FindAffineShapeArgs` definition:

```
struct FindAffineShapeArgs
{
    FindAffineShapeArgs(float x, float y, float s, float pixelDistance, float type, float response, const Wrapper &wrapper) :
        x(x), y(y), s(s), pixelDistance(pixelDistance), type(type), response(response), wrapper(std::cref(wrapper)) {}

    float x, y, s;
    float pixelDistance, type, response;
    std::reference_wrapper<Wrapper const> wrapper;
};
```

The Top 5 Parallel Regions by Potential Gain  in the summary view shows only one region (the only one)

[image]

Look at the "/OpenMP Region/OpenMP Barrier-to-Barrier"  grouping, this is the order of the most expensives loops:

- The 3th loop:

  ## pragma omp for schedule(dynamic) nowait

  for(int i=0; i

  is the most expensive one (as I already knew) and here's a screenshot of the expended view:

[image]

As you can see, many functions are from OpenCV, which exploits IPP and is (should be) already optimized. Expanding the two other functions (interpolate and samplePatch) shows a [No call stack information]. Same for all the other functions (in other regions too).

The 2nd most expensive region is the second parallel for:

```
#pragma omp for collapse(2) schedule(dynamic) nowait
for(int i=0; i<levels; i++)
    for (int j = 2; j < scaleCycles; j++){
    findLevelKeypoints(localfindAffineShapeArgs, hessResps[/*...*], /*...*/); //populate localfindAffineShapeArgs with push_back
}
```

Here's the expanded view:

[image]

And finally the 3th most expensive is the first loop:

```
#pragma omp for collapse(2) schedule(dynamic)
for(int i=0; i<levels; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= scaleCycles; j++)
    {
       hessResps[/**/] = hessianResponse(/*...*/);
    }
```

Here's the expended view:

[image]

**If you want to know more, please use my attached VTune files or just ask!**

Comment: You should try to summarize the problem and your question at the beginning, and then eventually provide all the data. As it is now, it is too long to read

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Antonio , I updated the question with a small intro, check it out.

Comment: I'm sorry I have no experience at all neither with x86 hardware optimization nor with those diagnostic tools, I just got notified to have a look at this. On my ARM machines I avoid mixing `openmp` and `tbb`. `opencv` functions run perfectly balanced with `tbb`, while outside `opencv` I use `openmp`. I can't dive deep enough into your project to judge whether this is the problem. Did you try to break it down to reproduce with the smallest possible complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the info in this [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-and-the-intel-ipp-library), especially the part about "Nested OpenMP" since Intel IPP already uses OpenMP in their implementation. From my experience with Intel IPP and OpenMP, if you are doing some other type of multi-threading and when each of the created threads gets to the OpenMP calls performance was really bad. Also, you can try having ***#pragma omp parallel for*** for each of the parallel regions instead of ***#pragma omp for*** and getting rid of the outer ***#pragma omp parallel***